# CSS div/element position issue

Tags: html, css, position

I have some position problems with some divs/tables.

Website dump: http://www.speedyshare.com/2yyuC/Screenshot-2014-11-11-at-08.58.24.png

As you can see on the picture 2 of the images are lower then the rest. At first the menu to the right was lower too (I guess this div is making the issue) but then I change to position:relativ for #menucontainer (the div for the menu) and in that way put the menu on the correct position. But as you can see 2 images are still affected by the #menucontainer. Any Ideas how I solve this?

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <div id="navposition">
                <div id="loggo">
                    <div class="loggocenter">
                        LodisKUNG.org
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="search">
                    <form id="searchform">
                        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for titles...">
                        <button class="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="menucontainer">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="menuhome"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li id="menuforum"><a href="index.html">Forum</a></li>
                        <li id="menuabout"><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                        <li id="menucontact"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <div id="sectioncenter">
                <div id="title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlename">
                                The walking dead - Days gone by  
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="titlepic">
                              <a href="#"><img src="twd.jpg" alt="twd"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlename">
                                The walking dead - Days gone by  
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="titlepic">
                              <a href="#"><img src="twd.jpg" alt="twd"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlename">
                                The walking dead - Days gone by  
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="titlepic">
                              <a href="#"><img src="twd.jpg" alt="twd"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlename">
                                The walking dead - Days gone by  
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="titlepic">
                              <a href="#"><img src="twd.jpg" alt="twd"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlename">
                                The walking dead - Days gone by  
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="titlepic">
                              <a href="#"><img src="twd.jpg" alt="twd"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlename">
                                The walking dead - Days gone by  
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="titlepic">
                              <a href="#"><img src="twd.jpg" alt="twd"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlename">
                                The walking dead - Days gone by  
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="titlepic">
                              <a href="#"><img src="twd.jpg" alt="twd"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlename">
                                The walking dead - Days gone by  
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="titlepic">
                              <a href="#"><img src="twd.jpg" alt="twd"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlename">
                                The walking dead - Days gone by  
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="titlepic">
                              <a href="#"><img src="twd.jpg" alt="twd"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="title">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlename">
                                The walking dead - Days gone by  
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="titlepic">
                              <a href="#"><img src="twd.jpg" alt="twd"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* HTML5 CSS3 layout elements */
header {
height:30px;
background-color: #000000;
border-bottom:5px solid #c20000;
}


nav {
height:75px;
font-family: Sans-serif, Comic Sans MS;
}

section {
height:100%;
}

/* Over all CSS */

body {
margin:0px;
height:100%;
font-family: Sans-serif, Verdana;
}

/* Loggo design */

#loggo {
background-color:#c20000;
width:300px;
height:75px;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans";
font-size:35px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

.loggocenter {
width:250px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-top:10px;

}

/* Center section content */

#sectioncenter {
width:90%;
height:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

/* Center search function */

#search {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:440px;
top:10px;
position:relative;
}

/* Style Navigation Menu */

#menucontainer ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#menucontainer li {
display:inline;
float:left;
}

#menucontainer a {
height:100%;
width:90px;
Border-right:1px solid black;
background-color:#c20000;
display:block;
padding-left:auto;
padding-right:auto;
font-size:18px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans";
color:#000000;
}

#menucontainer a:hover {
color:#FFFFFF;
}

#menucontainer {
float: right;
margin-bottom:1px;
position:relative;
top:-142px;
}

#navposition {
width:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:0px;
height:75px;
}

#menuforum a {
background-color:green;
}

#menuabout a {
background-color:blue;
}

#menucontact a {
background-color:yellow;
}

/* Search form design */

*:focus {
outline:none;
}

#searchform input {
height:50px;
width:350px;
border-radius:5px;
font-size:20px;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans";
padding:5px;
border:3px solid black;
}

#searchform button {
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans";
font-size:20px;
height:50px;
border:3px solid black;
}

/* Design looped titles */

#title {
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:5px;
float:left;
}

.titlepic img {
width:220px;
height:350px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
display: block;
}

#title table {
border:5px solid #f7f7f7;
border-radius:5px;
}

.titlename {
border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```

Sorry for posting for the whole code, but im not sure if it is actully the menucontainer thats making the issue, It could also be the tables or something else..

Thanks for help!

Comment: better to use jsfiddle or similar tool

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7r38qk19/ working on one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need clear floating of the element, Just add the below code above the section tag

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

its works!

Comment: I have never seen or used this code before, is it HTML5 or CSS3? How ever, it works! Thanks!

Comment: @Alex it is called the "clear fix" hack. You can find more about it here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

The searchbox pushes the element down.

Give the nav element a height. e.g. 230px

You need some alignment on your elements. Give some elements a display: block; so the align with each other.

I just added this:

```
nav,
header {
    display: block;
}
section {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I will try that. But it is not the search box, the issue was already there before I added the search box. The menu was pushing the image down at start, but after correcting the position of the menu using relative, the images was still pushed away..

Comment: the nav element does already have a hight in the CSS file (75px)

Comment: In general you have some problems with the size of you elements. See my edit above